# How many bits long,at most, is the seed in the randomSeed() function?

Tags: led

I can not find a concrete reference to how many bits long the (input) seed for the  randomSeed() function is for Arduino given here

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/random-numbers/randomseed/

In the above webpage , though it is the official Arduino document for randomSeed(), it does not concretely say if the maximum bit length of the seed is 8,16 or 32 bits.

I think it is 16 bits long (in other words the seed is in the
range of integers 0 and 65535). So for example the maximum input to randomSeed would be expressed as randomSeed(65535).

But I do not know for sure if the seed input is 16 bits at most.
So my question is the seed used in randomSeed() 16 bit length at most  (thus having a maximum value of 65535).
32 bits is comparable to a 32bit windows desktop computers so I think 32 bits is too large for the input seed to randomSeed(). I am also using an Arduino Uno with Arduino IDE version 1.6.7 (if that matters regarding the input bit length of the seed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated on the page you link to:

> `seed`: number to initialize the pseudo-random sequence. Allowed data types: `unsigned long`.

Therefore it's 32 bits, since that is what `unsigned long` is.